# lualatex and polyglossia with \setdefaultlanguage{german} does not work after recent texlive update

Tags: biblatex, luatex, polyglossia

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\begin{document}
Hallo Welt!
\end{document}
```

And here is the error message:

```
(/mnt/software/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
 (/mnt/software/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-german.ldf

Package polyglossia Warning: \setlocalhyphenmin useless for unknown language ger
man on input line 6.


Package polyglossia Warning: You asked for `ngerman' but only `german' hyphenati
on is available! on input line 68.

(/mnt/software/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babelsh.def))
(./test2.aux
! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
<recently read> \l@german 

l.3 \select@language {german}

?
```

Setting `\setdefaultlanguage{english}` works well.

Thanks
Georg

Update: The minimal example above works well if `german` is replaced by `ngerman`. Nevertheless, adding the line `\usepackage{biblatex}` again produces an error. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
Hallo Welt!
\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
(/mnt/software/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))

Package biblatex Warning: Upgrade package 'polyglossia' to >v1.42.0 recommended.



! Package biblatex Error: No default polyglossia language defined.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \begin{document}

?
```

Comment: Bad bug indeed.

Comment: I added an issue to the polyglossia bug tracker. https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/129

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'd say it's a bug introduced with the new release of `babel` that somehow makes impossible for polyglossia to load the patterns for the requested language(s). Of course it's a duty of `polyglossia` to do it properly, but apparently `babel` changed the API.

Comment: @egreg: The change is certainly due to the new babel version. But I'm not sure that one should call it a bug. I'm also not sure that e.g. \csname lu@texhyphen@loaded@\the\language\endcsname  was an official "API". Imho Arthur will have to decide if he either asks babel to revert some changes or adapt polyglossia.

Comment: using ngerman instead of german avoids the error but doesn't solve the underlying problem. I suggest to use \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} until polyglossia and/or babel is updated (or go back to the previous babel).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Using ngerman does not avoid the error when using biblatex, see the update of my original post. But your suggest to use \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} works, also with biblatex. Thanks for that.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed now.

Comment: @Simifilm: In connection with biblatex it still does not work after all texlive updates. See the second updated minimal example in my original post.

Comment: Polyglossia is about to be updated as far as I know (that's the biblatex warning ... there are some new hooks which biblatex needs in polyglossia >1.42.0)

Comment: It also seems that csquotes has been updated and relies on some new hooks in polyglossia >1.42.0?

Comment: This biblatex error is because polyglossia has no `ngerman-gloss.ldf` file and it skips setting `\bbl@main@language` as a result. I'll ask the polyglossia maintainer about this.

Comment: Looks like babel 3.9q reintroduced the problem :(

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: I'm still waiting for a polyglossia update ... I raised a ticket there a while ago.

Comment: As of today (October 1, 2016) neither example raises errors, provided in the second one the language call is according to `polyglossia` rules, that is, `german` and not `ngerman`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can not be reproduced any more. It was due to several bugs in several packages, and the actual problem shifted over time.