# LuaLatex | Biblatex & biber | UTF-8 Citation Problem when not using luainptenc

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber, unicode, german

Why do I have to use the *luainputenc* when every program is using UTF-8 encoding?

### Example

**good**
[image: The way it should be]

**Bad**
[image: Missing Characters]

---

**Tex Code** // Please use lualatex

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
%\usepackage{polyglossia} cannot be used: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291425/lualatex-and-
polyglossia-with-setdefaultlanguagegerman-does-not-work-after-re

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} % Please turn on and off

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex} %biber war fehlerhaft / sorting wird verwendet damit es der Reihenfolge entpsricht
\addbibresource{biblo.bib}
\begin{document}
    Test \cite{test}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

**Bib Code** // Please use biblatex and biber

```
@article{test,
author={Günter Frö},
title = {Wörter},
journal = {Wörter in Österreich},
year = {2013}
}
```

Comment: why can't you use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` ?

Comment: @RunarTrollet `inputenc` does nothing useful with luatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't realise this was a luatex-only question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you mean fontspec not fontenc

Comment: you are using classic 7bit fonts, rather than use `luainputenc` it would be better to add `\usepackage{fontspec`} and use Unicode encoded fonts

Comment: See also [Biblatex + Xelatex does not display accents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281116/35864) which is about LuaTeX, but the issue is essentially the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear why using LuaLaTeX, but here it is.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
author={Günter Frö},
title = {Wörter},
journal = {Wörter in Österreich},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  bibencoding=utf8
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self-contained.

[image]

Why do you need `luainputenc`? Because you're using legacy fonts, which have no character in the slots pointed at by Unicode characters above code 127.

Otherwise, use `fontspec`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
author={Günter Frö},
title = {Wörter},
journal = {Wörter in Österreich},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  bibencoding=utf8
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The output is essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

After trying to figure out the [difference](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc) between those two:
As I understand it, **fontspec** seems to be in a UTF-8 editor the "better" choice, when using lualatex or Xelatex

Comment: I need LuaLatex because of Lua Scripting